# Disable WooCommerce order email notification only when a specific product is purchased alone

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders, email-notifications

The customer requested me to disable email notification for free products in WoocCmmerce, but only in case the order contains this free product id = 5274

If the order includes this free product and any other product, the order email notification should be trigger.

This is the code I use now:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'disable_notification_free_product', 10, 2);
function disable_notification_free_product($recipient, $order)
{
    
    $page = $_GET['page'] = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
    if ('wc-settings' === $page) {
        return $recipient;
    }

    if (!$order instanceof WC_Order) {
        return $recipient;
    }
    //the product id is 5274    
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $items_cart = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); 
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        if ($product_id == 5274 and $items_cart == 1) {
            $recipient = '';
        }
        return $recipient;
    }
}
```

The code works before adding "and $items_cart == 1" to disable the email notification when the free product is in the order, but after adding the "and $items_cart == 1" nothing changed. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()` should only be used with the `$cart` object, with the `$order` object you can use `count( $order->get_items() )`

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order( $recipient, $order, $email ) {
    // Avoiding backend displayed error in WooCommerce email settings
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient;
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $key => $item ) {
        // Product ID
        $product_id = $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();

        // Product ID occurs and count is equal to 1
        if ( in_array( $product_id, array( 5274 ) ) && count( $order->get_items() ) == 1 ) {
            $recipient = '';
            break;
        }
    }

    return $recipient;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'filter_woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 10, 3 );
```